# Prioritize RabbitMQ consumer message consumption

Tags: php, python, rabbitmq

I'm working on a project with RabbitMQ and involves connected many consumers to a queue. I would like to know if there is a way to **specify which consumer gets "priority" on consuming messages from the queue**. Some of the consumers are better suited for the job and if they are available I would like to direct messages to them first before the other consumers.

I'm using the latest version of RabbitMQ (as of time of writing). I have a PHP publisher and Python Consumers.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by `Some of the consumers are better suited for the job`? Are there two types of consumers for the same queue?

Comment: Yes. I have physical computers as consumers, but they don't have the same specs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from Ibakken from the RabbitMQ Slack forum: https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html